# How to crack a Linear Congruential Generator (LCG)

Tags: random

The full question is: How to crack a Linear Congruential Generator when a, c and m in the LCG formula. I googled this question and I found what I wanted:

here is the question: https://brilliant.org/problems/breaking-linear-congruential-generators/

and here is the screenshot of the answer (you need to make an account, to see the answer):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYzqF.jpg

The problem is that I don't understand the answer.

1.) I do not understand this equation from the answer (what is this equation and why is it used): $$Z_n = Y_nY_{n+2}- Y^2_{n+1}$$

2) And I don't understand how a and c are found afterwards.

Any help is apprecciated

Also I am aware that there are other methods to solve this question for example by using a matrix: [Calculation for linear congruential generator: Setting up equations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1850847/calculation-for-linear-congruential-generator-setting-up-equations)

Thank you

Comment: This is an interesting question. You can improve it if you translate the image text into [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the formulas in the picture.

**Part 1:** With $Y_n \equiv a Y_{n-1} \pmod m$ you get
$$Y_{n+1} \equiv a Y_{n} \equiv a^2Y_{n-1} \pmod m$$
$$Y_{n+2} \equiv a Y_{n+1} \equiv  a^3Y_{n-1} \pmod m$$
and therefore 
$$Z_n \equiv Y_{n}Y_{n+2} - Y_{n+1}^2 \equiv  (a\cdot a^3 - (a^2)^2) Y_{n-1} \equiv  0 \pmod m$$

Thus $Z_n = m\times z_n$ is a multiple of $m$ and (as claimed in the image) for a sufficient number of samples $\{X_n\}$ the gcd of corresponding $Z_n$ is expected to be $m$.

---

**Part 2:** If you accept $m := 1000000007$ from the gcd calculation the two linear 
$$a X_1 + b \equiv  X_2 \pmod m$$
$$a X_2 + b \equiv  X_3 \pmod m$$
congruences can be solved as follows: First compute the modular multiplicative inverse $(X_1-X_2)^{-1} \equiv 560056067 \pmod m$ (this is usually done with the
Extended Euclidean Algorithm or Euler's theorem, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse#Computation),
for single values you can use an online calculator, e.g. https://planetcalc.com/3311/
with the input $X_1-X_2 = 587411898,  m=1000000007$ or with Wolfram Alpha
`solve (720555190-133143292)x = 1 mod 1000000007`)
and then 
$$a \equiv (X_2-X_3) (X_1-X_2)^{-1} \equiv 782674123\times 560056067 \equiv 1664525 \pmod m$$
$$b\equiv X_2 - a X_1 = 133143292 - 1664525\times 720555190 \equiv  13904216 \pmod m$$
This is done like the solving of a usual system of linear equations. Subtract the second from the first equation and get $a$
$$aX_1 - a X_2 \equiv a(X_1-X_2)\equiv X_2-X_3 \pmod m$$
$$a \equiv (X_2-X_3)(X_1-X_2)^{-1} \pmod m$$
and $b$ from the first equation.

Comment: hello again. I don't understand part 2 mainly because I don't know anything about modular inverses. Can you show me any links that could help me with this topic or elaborate on how you found that: 
$$ (X_2 - X_1)^{-1} = 560056067 \hspace{0.2cm} (mod \hspace{0.2cm} m) $$

and why for finding "a" you need to calculate: $$ (X_2−X_3)*(X_2 - X_1)^{-1} $$

Thanks

Comment: @george-v: See the edit (in the old version I swapped the indices, sorry for that).

Comment: One last question :))
How did you solve this linear congruence:

$$ (X_2−X_3) = 782674123 $$

Comment: @george-v: This is simple modular arithmetic: $X_2-X_3 = -217325884$ is negative, so add $m$ and get
$$X_2-X_3 \equiv -217325884 \equiv -217325884 + 1000000007 = 782674123.$$
This is the manual calculation, actually I did it using Maple. You can use other programs, e.g. Python, Pari/GP etc.