# How do I go about finding the nth term of this recursive sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, modular-arithmetic, recurrence-relations, random

I'm currently investigating the feasibility of acquiring the $n$th term of the recursive sequence used for a linear congruential generator. If you're unfamiliar with this sequence, I've included it below;
$$
U_{n+1}=(aU_n+b)\mod{m}
$$
Is this possible? If so, how do I go about acquiring the equation for the nth term

Whilst it may be possible to acquire the $n$th term of the sequence without considering the $\mod m$ and subsequently applying the modulo at the end of the equation.
Issues arise when computationally implementing such an algorithm due to the substantially large scale of numbers used for the $a$ and $b$ values

Thanks in advance! -Finn

**EDIT:** This issue has been resolved, the resource I used is attached; https://www.nayuki.io/page/fast-skipping-in-a-linear-congruential-generator

Comment: Well, have you  tried examples?  You should see that it is periodic.

Comment: @DietrichBurde  I guess the "mod $m$" makes it "congruential".

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator)

Comment: Ah, I wanted to say "modulariential".

Comment: Is it a duplicate of [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1850847/calculation-for-linear-congruential-generator-setting-up-equations) then? At least, we can find then the $n$-th term.

Comment: If this had a nice closed form, then it would not be useful for generating pseudo-random numbers.

Comment: This was a great starting point Jean, thank you! However, I had to research further to investigate the modulo implementation. Link for anyone looking for the resource I used: https://www.nayuki.io/page/fast-skipping-in-a-linear-congruential-generator